# Аннотация phpDoc для phpUnit

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit, codecoverage, phpdoc

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть ли такая аннотация к методу в `'phpDoc'`, которая могла бы сообщить сборщику отчета `'CodeCoverage'` о том, что данный метод не надо добавлять в отчет и помечать его красным цветом, потому что он не протестирован?

Нашел только аннотации `'@codeCoverageIgnoreStart / @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd'` которые делают что надо, отключают проверку кода, но этот способ очень неудобный, так как создает лишний шум в коде...

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я глупец...

Вопрос решен: [`Ignoring Code Blocks`](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.ignoring-code-blocks)

```
Example 11.4: Using the @codeCoverageIgnore, @codeCoverageIgnoreStart and @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd annotations

<?php
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
    }
}

class Bar
{
    /**
     * @codeCoverageIgnore
     */
    public function foo()
    {
    }
}

if (FALSE) {
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
    print '*';
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
}
?>
```